# How to import background color from HTML to Excel with VBA Macro

Tags: html, internet-explorer, excel, vba

i try to get some information out of a table within a website by macro to an excel table. usually I just use

```
ie2.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
ie2.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
```

and paste it to any excel sheet which is enough for my needs. but the website was changed. the problem is now, that I need to get the information of website cell with the following code:

```
<tr class="odd"><td><a href="xxxxxxx">
<img border="0" src="letter.png" title="Titel0" /></a><td></td>
<td><img title="VServer Usage" style="background-color:#00dd00" border="0" src="/ce.png" />&nbsp;<a   
href="testtesttest">blablabla</a></td>
<td><a href="http://maps.google.de/" target="_blank">TEST TEST</a></td>
<td><img border="0" src="/damage.png" title="Titel1"/></a></td>
<td></td><td><img border="0" src="/card.png" title="Titel2"/></a></td>
<td></td><td><img border="0" src="/key.png" title="Titel3" /></a></td>
<td><img border="0" src="/immo.png" title="Titel4" /></a></td>
<td><img border="0" src="/locked.png" title="Titel5" /></a></td><td>101</td>
<td>102</td><td>103</td><td>104</td><td>105</td><td>106</td><td>107</td><td>Name</td>
</tr>

// and then it starts with the next line which has the same structure
```

by that code I need to get the value for the background color (which can be #00dd00 or #000000 or #ff0000 or #0000ff) and paste it to excel cell B5. then the macro need to get the background color value below the one before and paste it to the cell B6 (and so on and so on).

any idea how to realize that?

Here is my first Idea: I parse through the whole sourcecode, look for a certain string and copy the following charakters with that code:

```
Dim strCountBody As String
Dim lStartPos As Long
Dim lEndPos As Long
Dim TextIWant As String
Dim Textpos As Integer
Dim searchchar As String

searchchar = "VServer Usage" 


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set WebBrowser1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebBrowser1.Visible = True ' zum testen anzeigen
WebBrowser1.Navigate "wwww.www..www"
While WebBrowser1.readyState <> 4
    'Warten, bis Seite geladen ist
    DoEvents
Wend

strCountBody = WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML
textpos = InStr(5500, strCountBody, searchchar, vbTextCompare)

TextIWant = Mid(strCountBody, Textpos, 25)

Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("J1").Value = TextIWant
Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("K1").Value = Textpos
```

That seems to work. The positions are correct BUT the search result is only: VServer Usage" border="0", which means that the whole part

```
style="background-color:#00dd00"
```

is not found and ignored. I also tried it with:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML
WebBrowser1.Document.body.outerHTML
WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerText
WebBrowser1.Document.body.outerText
```

but all with the same result :(

Comment: I thought about and came to the idea, that I might the easier way to find the string "style="background-color:#" in html, copy the next 6 characters and paste these to a cell in excel and afterwards find the next string and copy the following characters...and so on and so on. any idea?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the structure of the restof the page (does the table containing this row have an id ? Is it the only table on the page, or are there multiple/nested tables?)  Do you need all rows from this table?  In general, if you can get a reference to that row element, you could try something like `myRow.cells(2).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).style.backgroundColor`

Comment: @TimWilliams the page contains only that table with about 2500 rows. so i preferred copy&paste for now as the easiest way. but now I need to get this colorcode on each row and paste each to a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
Dim tbl, rw

For Each tbl in ie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each rw in tbl.body.rows

       debug.print rw.cells(2).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).style.backgroundColor

    Next rw
Next tbl
```

Comment: it doesnt give any error but doesnt do anything. have a look at my discription, because I changed something which I figured out. thanks

Comment: So there is no output at all to the Immediate pane in the VB Editor?

Comment: unfortunately not. dont know why. maybe I did something wrong. could you post the whole code I should use? or tell me something about why my search for the background-color is ignored? thank you