# get background color from website

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

Hi im trying to get the backgound color from a website to compare it for other operations. Just like the Background color of the buy button of the web site.

```
Sub Colorfinder()
Dim oIE As New InternetExplorer
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim tags As Object
Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLtag As IHTMLElement

With oIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
    Set oHtml = .document
End With


'this is needed to wait until the page is totally loaded
Do: Set tags = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderBookPanel_text_3fH-g")(0): DoEvents: Loop While tags Is Nothing


'getting the element that it is about
Do: Set HTMLtags = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_toggle_31S34"): DoEvents: Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0

Set HTMLtag = HTMLtags(0).Children(0)
Debug.Print HTMLtag.innerText

'this is the problem
Debug.Print HTMLtag.Style.backgroundColor

End Sub
```

i got this idea from an otherstuck overflow user. but it didn´t work. [link stuckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126308/how-to-import-background-color-from-html-to-excel-with-vba-macro/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```vb
Sub Colorfinder()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Loop
        With .Document
            Do While .getElementsByClassName("OrderBookPanel_text_3fH-g").Length = 0: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_toggle_31S34").Length = 0: DoEvents: Loop
            With .parentWindow
                .execScript "var e = document.getElementsByClassName('OrderForm_toggle_31S34')[0].children[0];"
                .execScript "e.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');"
            End With
            Debug.Print .getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_toggle_31S34")(0).Children(0).Style.backgroundColor ' rgb(77, 165, 60)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

`.execScript` executes JScript code within HTML document, that is why syntax uses `var`, `'`, `[]` and `;`, etc., variable `e` is the target node declared in the document scope, and it's actual computed background value just put into `.backgroundColor` property. Using `.execScript` is the only way I found to get to `window.getComputedStyle` method, which actually do the job.

Comment: Can you explain how this works. What does the two lines with .execScript mean? Why did you use ' and [] instead  of " and ()? And what ist this e Element?...

Answer (score 1):

Is this *really* something that needs to be automated?

The background-color of the BUY button is:

[image: #4da53c]
<sub>(Click for more about **`#4da53c` *Strong Sap Green***.)</sub>

---

Right-click any element on a web page and choose `Inpsect Element` to find the color under the style properties (specific location depends on your browser).

Or, use a color detection utility such as:

- [Instant Eyedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/) which runs in the background. You click the icon in your system tray and then any spot on your screen to identify the color of the pixel.
- [Firefox add-on: colorPicker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorpicker/) same idea, but a plug-in.

Others are available for other browsers, and there are also websites that will identify colors from uploaded images, URLs, entire website color schemes, etc.

Comment: thanks for your fast aswer. But thats not what i wanted. I need to find the  color using vba so that i can compare it [If HTMLtag.Style.backgroundColor = "#4da53c" Then
        Debug.Print "grün"
    Else
        Debug.Print "error"
    End If]

Comment: `If HTMLtag.Style.backgroundColor = "#4da53c" Then`
        `Debug.Print "grün"`
    `Else`
        `Debug.Print "error"`
    `End If`