# VBA IE Automation to return javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, vba, internet-explorer

After connecting to IE through VBA I used to be able to import created javascript variables like so…

```
IEObj.Document.parentWindow.execScript “var jsValue = ‘abc’”
vbValue = IEObj.Document.parentWindow.jsValue
```

But recently it’s started returning a “Object doesn’t support this property or method” 438 error?

Nothing on the VBA code has been changed, so I guess something has changed on the website I’m using the code on?

I know I could create a hidden html text box to store and retrieve a value from there.  But looking for suggestions if anyone has a direct method similar to the above?

Noting: I've tried the code in VBS, and it works fine there.  Just not in Excel-VBA?

Comment: I encountered the same issues accessing to variables created within `window` scope, and to methods. Thus [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245023/2165759) had to resort to workaround to get return value instead of direct method call from VBA.

Comment: thanks @omegastripes I suspect it might be when https is used instead of http, cause that's the thing that has changed, and I noticed it in your example too?

Comment: Not sure, but the issue might be caused by IE document mode / browser mode / compatibility / security zones settings, or IE and host processes bitness (e. g. IE running 32 bit and Excel 64 bit). Also take a look at [the code samples](http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?id=9514): VBA code faults, at the same time VBS works fine.